# Encrypt Rest Communication

Tags: web-services, security, rest, encryption

At the company I work for, we are developing two different systems. These systems will exchange a few information. We thought to make them communicate through Rest paradigm. Now the trouble is that these informations must travel in a secure way (encrypted). I read that Rest is indipendent from the security, then i would want ask you some suggestion about this problem.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: How much do you know about REST and HTTP?

Comment: I worked about Rest during my thesis and i work for this company from a little time (about 1 month)

Answer (score 0):

REST is an architectural style. It makes as much sense to say you thought of communicating through REST  as it makes sense saying you want to connect two buildings through Spanish Colonial.

What you probably mean is that you want to make them communicate through HTTP. If you want the information to be encrypted, just use HTTPS and basic authentication on every client-server interaction.